# In Minecraft SMP, if there are no players online, do any monsters spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have heard that monsters only spawn within a fixed radius of the player in single-player mode. Is it different in SMP, or is it that because there are no players that no monsters can spawn?

Comment: If a tree falls in the forest, and no ones around to hear it, does it make a sound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it works the same in SMP. You can find the algorithm at [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn). Basically they don't spawn closer than 24 blocks, or farther away than an 272 x 272 area from a player. So no player = no spawns.

You can test this yourself by joining a server that has been empty for a while (I'm not sure how long it takes for mobs to despawn) and you'll notice that it always takes a few moments before any kind of mob shows up.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I had left my server without players for a couple of days, and was slightly surprised as to why no monsters had spawned.